# Ember.js and Highcharts: how to render a graph only after slow-loading model data has been loaded?

Tags: ember.js, highcharts

**UPDATE**: we have found a solution for this that seems pretty elegant. I've added all relevant code at the bottom.

We're evaluating Ember.js for the upcoming big rewrite of our main product, an analytical dashboard. Our product's focus is making huge data sets manageable and one way we accomplish this is by using graphs. So, I'm currently testing using Highcharts with Ember.js.

My question is: **what is the best way to deal with slow-loading server side data that is used as the source for a graph?**

That is: where in the code below should I make changes to make sure that the Highcharts graph gets rendered only **after** the JSON data that it renders has returned from the server?

Currently, I have the following routes in Ember:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'panel', ->
    @route 'gender'

App.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'
  rootUrl: '/'
```

In this case, the **panel/gender** route should show a page with a Highcharts graph, showing the distribution of a research panel.

The `PanelRoute`:

```
App.PanelRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.PanelMetric.find()
```

The `App.PanelMetric` model: (I'm not using Ember Data here because my JSON structure is not compliant with Ember Data's conventions)

```
App.PanelMetric = Ember.Object.extend()

App.PanelMetric.reopenClass
  find: ->
    $.getJSON('/panel_metrics.json?callback=?').then (response) ->
      App.PanelMetric.create(response)
```

The `PanelGenderController`:

```
App.PanelGenderController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'panel'
```

The `panel/gender` template (uses Emblem.js):

```
App.GraphView id=gender_graph contentBinding=controllers.panel.content
```

The `App.GraphView` view:

```
App.GraphView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'div'
  classNames: [ 'highcharts' ]

  didInsertElement: ->
    App.GraphController.render('gender_graph', @content)
```

The `GraphController` has a `render` method that creates the actual Highcharts graph.

---

**UPDATE**: as mentioned above, we've found an (in our eyes) elegant solution for this. It's actually rather obvious: we simply an if/else statement in Handlebars that, depending on the `isLoaded` property of the controller, shows a "Loading..." message or the actual graph.

We set `isLoading` to false initially. In the router we load the data with `$.getJson` and when the data has loaded from the server we set `isLoaded` to `true` on the controller. Furthermore, in the router, we use the `deactivate` callback to set `isLoaded` to `false` when browsing away from the page.

Updated `PanelGenderController`:

```
App.PanelGenderController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  isLoaded: false

  data: ( ->
    gender = @content.gender

    # Transform "gender" to something Highcharts understands, return an Array
  ).property('content')

  categories: ( ->
    gender = @content.gender

    # Transform "gender" to an Array of category names,
    # used for the x-axis of the graph
  ).property('content')
```

Updated `PanelGenderRoute`:

```
App.PanelGenderRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    $.getJSON('/panel_metrics.json?callback=?').then (response) ->
      controller.set('content', App.PanelMetric.create(response))
      controller.set('isLoaded', true)

  deactivate: ->
    @get('controller').set('isLoaded', false)
```

Updated `PanelRoute`: is now empty, uses the generated route from Ember.

Updated `PanelMetric` model:

```
App.PanelMetric = Ember.Object.extend()
```

Updated `GraphView` view:

```
App.GraphView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'div'
  classNames: [ 'highcharts', 'app-graph' ]

  didInsertElement: ->
    App.GraphController.render(@elementId, @content, @categories)
```

Updated `panel/gender` template:

```
if isLoaded
  App.GraphView id=gender contentBinding=data categoriesBinding=categories
else
  App.LoadingGraphView
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available at the time the question was asked, but you can just define a template with an id of `loading` and Ember.js will display it before the data from the model is available to you

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/